# How to sum values from all custom posts metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I got a metabox that hold a monthly budget per client...
that meta box is inside a custom post type called clients.
Inside that metabox the only thing entered is numbers.

I want to get the sum of all the clients.
Any ideas?

Altough i think its pure php.. somehow using foreach - to the request of @Fahd Murtaza i am trying to add parts of my metabox... i am using alchemy as the base to create my meta boxes so would add some parts.. Hope this doesnt confuse more..

```
<?php
// structure of my metabox usign alchemy
$clients = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_project_description',
    'title' => __('Client Info Card', 'sagive'),
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/clients-meta.php',
    'types' => array('portfolio'),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'autosave' => TRUE

));
```

.

```
// call for budget section in my meta box
<p>
<label><?php _e('Clients Budget:', 'sagive'); ?></label>
    <?php $mb->the_field('client_budget'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php $metabox->the_name('client_budget'); ?>" value="<?php $metabox->the_value('client_budget'); ?>"/>
</p>
```

.
The rest of the code is way to long and i think not relevant to show...  correct me if i am wrong and would add it via pastebin or similer..

.
**THIS IS HOW I QUERY THE POSTS...**

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );                    
    $count_posts_portfolio = wp_count_posts( 'portfolio' )->publish;
?>
```

Comment: Please share your metabox code.

Comment: my meta boxes are set using alchemy script so.. they are spread on many files.. i tried adding them to the question as organized as i can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming that you have a variable called `$posts` that contains all the posts (or easier: Post IDs) from some query.

You can then work with `$result` and process everything you need. Calling post data is easy, as the key would be the post ID.

```
// For other arguments look into @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
$posts = new WP_Query( 
     'post_type' => 'portfolio'
    ,'post_status' => 'publish'
);

foreach ( $posts as $post )
{
    $result[ $post->ID ]['post_data'] = $post->ID;
    $result[ $post->ID ]['meta_data'] = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
}

foreach( $result as $id => $data )
{
    // Do whatever you need to do with your meta data in here.
    print 'The title is: '.$post->post_title;

    // See your post data:
    print_r( $data['post_data'] );

    // See your meta data:
    print_r( $data['meta_data'] );
}
```

Comment: Sorry @kaiser.. i dont where to use that and how to turn $result[ $post->ID ] into a sum... i have added to my question the query i currently use... can share a more descriptive answer? :)

Comment: See update. But honestly: You can check about a hundred Qs here in WPSE to see how you access meta data. The same goes for WP Codex. And calculating the values from the meta data is basic php, non-WP stuff you can read about on php.net.

Comment: i can do the calculating no prob.. my problem was how to inside the loop... thanks man.. going to try your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,  // all the posts
    'post_type'   => 'clients'
);
$clients = get_posts( $args );

$total = 0;
foreach( $clients as $client ) {
    $single = get_post_meta( $client->ID, 'metakey_name_here', true );
    $total += $single;
}
```

`$total` should now contain the total for all the clients. `metakey_name_here` is going to be whatever `$metabox->the_name( 'client_budget' )` is, I presume that is set elsewhere, but I've never worked with the WP_Alchemy class, so I can't tell you definitively. If you need more functionality than [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) offers, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is gonna be the place I would look. Also, here's documentation on [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) in case you need it.